# Is there any way to insert data to mysql using backbonejs,html and java with out php

Tags: java, mysql, backbone.js

Is there any way to insert data to mysql using backbonejs,html and java with out php
im creating a html page with name,phone and email i want to insert this data
        into mysql db...
       if someone know please let me know...!!

Comment: could you please explain??

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need the Java MySQL Connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Here's a simple code example:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ;
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME", "usrname", "pswd") ;
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
String query = "select columnname from tablename ;" ;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;
```